Optimizing Fourier series computation time in python
I'm currently working on a code which requires the calculation of a
Fourier series more than a million times. Fourier series are
calculated using the same function below.
def fourier(ai, bi, angle, nb_harmonique):
     serie = 0.0
     for i in range(0, nb_harmonique):
         serie += ai[i] * np.cos(angle * (i+1)) + bi[i] * np.sin(angle * (i+1))
     return serie

Parameters ai and bi are one-dimensional arrays, containing float64
elements. The angle parameter is of type float64 and is simply an
angle value.
Fourier series are calculated using the @jit decorator (nopython=True,
fastmath=True) in the Numba module.
The calculation time for a call to the function performing the Fourier
series calculation is 2.7e-6 s.
Is there any way of reducing the computation time involved in this operation?
I've already tried using a matrix calculation rather than a loop to calculate the series. I've also tried parallelizing the loop.

Use something other than Python?

Find a fast library that has an implementation of the function you need.  Python is fast enough for most common tasks, but not for this kind of thing.  So in the python ecosystem there are specialized libraries written in optimized C/C++ when you need the kind of speed that python code can't deliver.
Try NumPy first.

Why is NumPy fast?
looping, indexing, etc., in the code - these things are taking place,
of course, just “behind the scenes” in optimized, pre-compiled C code.
Vectorized code has many advantages, among which are:
vectorized code is more concise and easier to read
fewer lines of code generally means fewer bugs
the code more closely resembles standard mathematical notation (making
it easier, typically, to correctly code mathematical constructs)
vectorization results in more “Pythonic” code. Without vectorization,
our code would be littered with inefficient and difficult to read for
loops.Vectorization describes the absence of any explicit

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html

his code already uses numpy.

But it's still a tight loop in python.
